# HP UFT registry setting that allows other HP products to run test and components?

Tags: powershell, registry, hp-uft

I am attempting to create a powershell script that fully automates the UFT (HP's Unified Functional Testing 12.01) install and configuration process. Is there a registry setting that controls the "Allow other HP products to run tests and components" option that can be found in the UFT UI at Tools->Options->GUI Testing->Test Runs?

Comment: you should tag hp-uft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\QuickTest Professional\MicTest

Set AllowTDConnect  to 1
```